# JSON Data issues with js object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, key

Here's the deal, I have json data like that :

```
data{"key.name":"value"}
```

how can I use this in Javascript, because if I use the classic "data.key.name" I get an error due to the keyname being key.name ...
Do you see the problem ?

Thanks for the help :)

ps : Sorry if my english is not perfect, it's not my natural language.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keyName = data['key.name'];
```